# Error connecting to Redis from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster

I am using spring boot version 2.1.3 and trying to connect to cluster redis but I am getting

```
Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs
```

then I upgraded to spring boot version 3.2.2 and start getting another error

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot obtain initial Redis Cluster topology
```

any idea why I am not able to connect, although the redis server is accessable and I am passing the correct username,  password, host and port to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration for `LettuceConnectionFactory`.

```
 @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisStandAloneConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("127.0.0.1", 6379));
    }
```

If you have properties file you can configure like

```
# Redis Config
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.data.redis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.data.redis.port=6379
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want cluster redis not standalone